# identify and convert have different ImageMagick versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave for photo upload but the image resizing function doesn't work properly. So I spent about 6 hours trying to figure it our on google. I tried uninstalling and installing ImageMagick as it seems to be the root of the problem. This did not help. So I then checked the versions of "identify" and "convert" which are presumably two utilities that come with ImageMagick. They report different ImageMagick version number, as pasted below:

63c55b$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.3-2 2011-10-23 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

63c55b$ identify --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.2-6 2011-03-16 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

This is right after I installed ImageMagick from source using make install. I don't know how to upgrade the version for identify to match that of convert. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands to find out the installation locations of your `convert` and `identify` binaries (I'm assuming you're on Linux or Mac OS X):

```
 which convert
 which identify
```

Should the directory for `convert` be different from that of `identify`: have a look if there is another identify in the same directory as `convert`.

If that doesn't help, try these commands to *List the Dynamic Dependencies* for each of the binaries:

```
 ldd `which convert`
 ldd `which identify`
```

(Dynamic dependencies are those libs that another lib or executable requires to load at runtime so it can run at all...) One of the two may be *'statically linked'* (and hence list no dynamic dependencies at all).